# High memory pressure Catalina Macbook Pro causing freezing?

Tags: hardware, memory, performance

My Macbook Pro has been running with really high memory recently, I think it might be what's caused the whole system to freeze 2 or 3 times over the last couple of weeks. I'll have a bunch of apps open then, maybe it's just that? But I don't think my usage habits have changed in the last 6 months (in fact previously I've done a lot of heavy RAM things, like working with large data sets / ML), and I wasn't experiencing any kind of freezing.

By "freezing" I mean that the whole system locks up, can't move mouse etc., display is still on, and it takes ~10secs to come back. Once it didn't come back and I had to do a hard restart.

Set up:
[image]

Looking at the Activity Monitor, the programs there definitely aren't using the 14GB of Memory Used, but from other articles here I see that this is normal. Maybe the high memory pressure isn't normal though. I'm really not using big RAM-heavy programs, and as i said, it's no heavier than what has been absolutely fine for the last months.
[image: Activity Monitor sorted descending by Memory]

Anyone else experienced this? Would high memory pressure cause the kinds of freezing that i've experienced? Any fixes?

Thanks,

Comment: Firstly, you're only viewing "My Processes". Switch to "All Processes" in the View menu. Also, Chrome is well known as a massive RAM hog. Try running things without Chrome, and see if that makes a difference. If not, then quit one more program - probably Teams next, then see what that does. Keep going till you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Ben, good spot, will do as you suggest.

Comment: @benwiggy, did as you suggested, your first hunch was right. Have move to MS Edge instead of Chrome and life is good again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @benwiggy's suggestion, I investigated which programmes were causing high RAM usage: it was Google Chrome. I have installed Microsoft Edge, which has all the features of Chrome (same extensions, appearance settings etc.) but doesn't hog memory. Very happy with it so far.

Smooth sailing for now:
[image]